# firebug in jsfiddle's results panel

Tags: javascript, firebug, jsfiddle

How do you enable firebug in jsfiddle and have it display in the results panel?

See what I mean here: http://cl.ly/image/262F3O2A3x1h

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to load [firebug lite](https://getfirebug.com/firebuglite) as a resource. Under the "Manage Resources" tab on the left, upload the file "firebug-lite-debug.js".

Comment: Thanks! Where is this documented, by the way? I search and skimmed the jsfiddle docs and didn't find any mention of it there.

Comment: It's not documented, since it's not really a feature of jsfiddle itself. Firebug lite is an external JavaScript library that you can load on to any page, including a jsfiddle

Comment: I think it could be added (docs are opensource BTW https://github.com/jsfiddle/jsfiddle-docs-alpha/)

Comment: just made a pull request :)

Answer (score 0):

Or if you choose jQuery framework, you can check "firebug lite" checkbox from options under framework selection.